# Generation of random data for tests

Tags: kotlin, unit-testing, testing, data-generation

In Java, I can do things with [EasyRandom](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jeasy/easy-random-core)

```java
final EasyRandom generator = new EasyRandom();
final MyDto dummy = generator.nextObject(MyDto.class);
// test
```

But I haven't found a suitable way to do something like this in Kotlin

Which libraries should be used to create fake test data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like KotlinFixture.

You can do things like this with it

```
val randomElement = fixture(listOf(<your objects>))
```

and other fake data generation.

https://github.com/appmattus/kotlinfixture